# Unable to access neither Partition Layout nor Option tab in Partition tab on Disk Utility

Tags: partition, core-storage, guid

I have a problem that I cannot select Option tab in Partition tab as shown in above screenshot. I wanted to convert my external hard disk to GUID partition table.

Thank you in advance for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add a complete screenshot of the Disk Utility window and the output of `diskutil list` entered in Terminal. The most important informations are missing.

Comment: Dear Klanomath,

Thank you for the reply. I added screenshots as per your request. Please help me check. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't partition disk1 freely because it contains a Core Storage Volume Group (disk1s2 -> disk2).

You can revert to a non-CoreStorage by booting to Macintosh HD (disk0s2) and opening Terminal.

Enter the following to get all necessary infos:

```
diskutil cs list
```

Example listing:

```
      CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
    |
    +-- Logical Volume Group A629E051-D7B0-4B8C-A803-074F62704636
        =========================================================
        Name:         System
        Status:       Online
        Size:         53946696192 B (53.9 GB)
        Free Space:   16777216 B (16.8 MB)
        |
        +-< Physical Volume 90C09FC0-4215-4871-901B-70E2C9C7D464
        |   ----------------------------------------------------
        |   Index:    0
        |   Disk:     disk0s2
        |   Status:   Online
        |   Size:     53946696192 B (53.9 GB)
        |
        +-> Logical Volume Family F6962E38-50E4-4458-BFE6-CF2E179352F5
            ----------------------------------------------------------
            Encryption Status:       Unlocked
            Encryption Type:         None
            Conversion Status:       NoConversion
            Conversion Direction:    -none-
            Has Encrypted Extents:   No
            Fully Secure:            No
            Passphrase Required:     No
            |
            +-> Logical Volume BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88
                ---------------------------------------------------
                Disk:                  disk2
                Status:                Online
                Size (Total):          53496696192 B (53.5 GB)
                Conversion Progress:   -none-
                Revertible:            Yes (no decryption required)
                LV Name:               System
                Volume Name:           System
                Content Hint:          Apple_HFS
```

If your Logical Volume is revertible enter:

```
diskutil cs revert lvUUID
```

*(lvUUID is the UUID of the Logical Volume)*

with the UUID of the example above

```
diskutil cs revert BD36C73D-860D-4DC6-B125-AD624F448B88
```

If the Logical Volume is encrypted you have to enter a passphrase.

After the conversion repartition the drive as needed.

---

If the LV isn't revertible you have to copy the content of the volume *21Tech* to another volume and delete the Logical Volume Group with:

```
diskutil cs delete lvgUUID
```

*(lvgUUID is the UUID of the Logical Volume Group)*

with the UUID of the example above

```
diskutil cs delete A629E051-D7B0-4B8C-A803-074F62704636
```

Then repartition the drive as needed.